# defining function animate() outside its parameter 'img' scope fails, using react useEffect

Tags: reactjs, image, scope, requestanimationframe

**Goal**: I want to define my animation() function outside of my React useEffect() hook (which loads the image for animating) because I only want to define it once, not every time a dependency changes.

**Problem**: Even though I am invoking the animation() function in the correct img scope (in img.onload), it fails if I declare the function outside of the img scope. Additionally, if I pass the parameter `img` into the definition animation(img) it also fails, which doesn't make any sense to me.

**Why this is confusing**: I have never before seen a scenario where the function definition needs to be declared in its parameters' scope. It usually only needs to be *invoked* in the parameter's scope. I've also never seen a function that fails by declaring the parameter in the definition.

**Code that does what I expect (kind of)**

to replicate this issue, make a create-react-app, and then replace the file "/src/App.js" with this code.

This component WORKS because the animation() function is defined inside the img scope in the useEffect() hook, and img is not passed as a parameter.
(i.e. function animation() {}; not function animation(img) {}).

*drag the circle over the image to use the App*

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [mouseCoords, setMouseCoords] = useState({ x: 10, y: 10 });
  const mouseRef = useRef({
    down: false
  });
  const canvasRef = useRef();
  const animRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      animation(); // || animation(img) .. invoking with img param is OK
    };
    img.src =
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*g6s1lvpfArJGorALkKNhvw.png";

    function animation() { // != animation(img) ..defining with img param throws error why??
      var canvas = canvasRef.current;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fill();
      animRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }

    return cancelAnimationFrame(animRef.current);
  }, [mouseCoords]);

  function getCanvasCoord(canvas, x, y) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      x: Math.round((x - rect.left) * (canvas.width / rect.width)),
      y: Math.round((y - rect.top) * (canvas.height / rect.height))
    };
  }

  const handleMouseDown = e => {
    mouseRef.current.down = true;
  };
  const handleMouseMove = e => {
    var { x, y } = getCanvasCoord(canvasRef.current, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    if (mouseRef.current.down) {
      setMouseCoords({ x, y });
    }
  };
  const handleMouseUp = e => {
    mouseRef.current.down = false;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        width={500}
        height={500}
      ></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't know why I have to define animation() inside the useEffect hook. Additionally, the app fails if I include in the img parameter

**Failing code example 1**

```
useEffect(() => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      animation(img); // animation(img) .. adding img param here is OK
    };
    img.src =
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*g6s1lvpfArJGorALkKNhvw.png";

    function animation(img) { //  animation(img) ..adding parameter to definition throws error why??
      var canvas = canvasRef.current;
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fill();
      animRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
    }
```

**Failing code example 2**

Another way this fails is trying to declare the animation function outside of the useEffect hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      animation(img);
    };
    img.src =
      "https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*g6s1lvpfArJGorALkKNhvw.png";

    return cancelAnimationFrame(animRef.current);
  }, [mouseCoords]);

  function animation(img) {
    var canvas = canvasRef.current;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fill();
    animRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }
```

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
animation
src/App.js:27
  24 | var canvas = canvasRef.current;
  25 | var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  26 | ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
> 27 | ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
     | ^  28 | ctx.beginPath();
  29 | ctx.arc(mouseCoords.x, mouseCoords.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  30 | ctx.fill();
View compiled
```

**Summary**: My app animation function has grown a lot, with many parameters and dependencies. I need to troubleshoot CPU issues, and I want to start by only declaring the function one time. Why can't I declare the function definition outside of the img.onload scope? What is so special about img parameter that it fails if I include it in function definition? I don't know how to begin simplifying my animation burden if I can't move the function itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) does pass a [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) parameter to your callback, so at second iteration, you are trying to draw a *number*, not the `Image`.

```js
const img = new Image();
animation( img );


function animation( img ) {
  console.log( img ); // first round: <img>, second round: a number
  if( img instanceof HTMLImageElement ) {
    requestAnimationFrame( animation );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand, you are saying that the requestAnimationFrame function is redefining img with a timestamp? I didn't know that, but I still am unable to define my function outside of the useEffect hook. Do you think I'm stuck because of this? Maybe I should just use setTimeout or setInterval?

Comment: Yes, the variable `img` inside the `animation` function is whatever the caller will pass as argument (would be `undefined` with `setTimeout(animation, time)`). I'm not sure why you need to move your function outside of useEffect, and declare `img` inside... One way around is to use `Function.prototype.bind`, this way you could do `const boundAnimation = animation.bind( null, img ); function animation( img, timestamp ) { ... requestAnimationFrame( boundAnimation ); }`

Comment: Somehow my interactive animation starts clamping up with prolonged user interaction. I don't understand what is happening. One of the things I wanted to troubleshoot was removing the function, and I realized I couldn't do it. I'm not sure if I need to. I will try to understand your second suggestion, though.

Comment: I wasn't able to bind img to the animation function. However, storing the img in a useRef hook let me disconnect the animation function from the useEffect scope. Inside useEffect : `img.onload = () => { imgRef.current = img; animate()} `.